# forward declaration and typename using new keyword

Tags: c++, namespaces, forward-declaration, fully-qualified-naming

I'm getting an error below in the class a declaring a new pointer of type b. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace B
{
    class b;
}
class a
{
    private:

    B::b* obj_b;

    public:

    a(){}
    ~a(){}
    void create()
    {
        b* obj_b = new b;
    }
};
class b
{
    private:

        a *obj_a;

    public:
        b()
        {
            obj_a->create();
        }
        ~b(){}
};
int main()
{
    b obj;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see an error, just a bunch of code. Maybe you forgot something?

Comment: and please change the names. Some more keystrokes won't harm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were many errors in your code. These are related to forward declaration, fully qualified name usage etc.

```
namespace B 
{ 
   class b; 
} 
class a 
{ 
private: 

   B::b* obj_b;            // change 1 (fully qualified name)

public: 
   void create();          // change 2 (can't use b's constructor now as B::b is not 
                           // yet defined)
   a(){} 
   ~a(){} 

}; 

class B::b                 // change 3 (fully qualified name)
{ 
private: 

   a *obj_a; 

public: 
   b() 
   { 
      obj_a->create(); 
   } 
   ~b(){} 
}; 

void a::create()             // definition of B::b's constructor visible now.    
{ 
   B::b* obj_b = new B::b;   // And here also use fully qualified name
} 

int main() 
{ 
   B::b obj; 

   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: @scriptingalias: Don't apologize for asking questions.

Answer (score 6):

```
b* obj_b = new b;
```

And there is your problem.  You can declare a pointer to a B because pointers are all the same size, but you cannot construct one or take one by value without providing the class definition to the compiler.  How would it possible know how to allocate memory for an unknown type?

Comment: Yeah its what I wrote on the first line but thanks it works now

Comment: Well, yes, you realized it was giving you an error, but obviously not why.